# Как на ноде выбрать что-то из mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Как правильно сделать выборку из mongodb, на нативном nodejs

```
 var db = new mongo.Db('learn', new mongo.Server('localhost', 27017, {}), {});

db.open(function(err, db) {
 db.collection('unicorns', function(err, collection) {
  var a = collection.find({color: 'red'});   
});
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если весь написанный выше код отрабатывает корректно, то осталось только преобразовать cursor в массив, делается это так:

```
 a.toArray(function( err, data ) {
   // for( var i=0; i<data.length; ++i ) {...}
 })
```

Для выборки единичной записи лучше использовать метод `findOne`.

Вообще [вот](http://nodejs.ru/290) неплохая статья по сабжу

###### примечание: У cursor'a, для получения документов, помимо метода toArray, так-же, существуют `each` и `nextObject`

Comment: а нечего что нода слушает один порт, а для монго прописывается другой
mongo.Server('localhost', 27017....

Comment: @Zow - так и должно быть, у тебя же mysql не на порте апача висит :D